# How to pass an object as a BlackBerry SOAP request parameter

Tags: web-services, soap, blackberry, request

I am New to BlackBerry development using Momentics. Now I want to send one object to SOAP request.

Here is my web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Login xmlns="http://shidhints.com/">
      <MyLoginCredentials>
        <Email>string</Email>
        <Password>string</Password>
      </MyLoginCredentials>
    </Login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my C++ code:

```
m_soap.setAction("http://shidhints.com/Login");
m_soap.setHost("mobile.shidhints.com");

QtSoapMessage request;
request.setMethod(QtSoapQName("Login", "http://shidhints.com/"));

request.addMethodArgument("Email", "http://shidhints.com/", email);
request.addMethodArgument("Password", "http://shidhints.com/", password);

// Submit the method request to the web service.
m_soap.submitRequest(request, "http://shidhints.com/Service.asmx");
```

Now I am getting an error like:

> Query failed: XML parse error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Resolved it Using the code,

```
QtSoapStruct *myStruct=new QtSoapStruct(QtSoapQName("MyLoginCredentials"));
myStruct->insert( new QtSoapSimpleType(QtSoapQName("Email"), email));
myStruct->insert( new QtSoapSimpleType(QtSoapQName("Password"),password));

request.addMethodArgument(myStruct);
```